# Would it be better to use "if x in (y, z)" over "if x == y or x == z"?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, if-statement, readability

Given this simple condition:

```
if x == y or x == z:
    print("Hello World!");
```

I understand that Python would first look to see if `x` is equal to `y` and if `x` is **not** equal to `y` it then it would check to see if `x` is equal to `z`, printing `Hello World!` if at least one of the conditions is `True`.

If I were to do this instead:

```
if x in (y, z):
    print("Hello World!");
```

To my understanding Python would iterate through the "yz" tuple and then print `Hello World!` if the value of `x` is in the "yz" tuple.

Which method would be faster / more efficient to use?
Would Python not bother to check if `x` was equal to `z` if `x` was equal to `y`?
Would Python still execute the code in the if statement if `x` was equal to `y` but **not** `z`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could always do benchmark tests for the first question. Not sure about second question. You could test for the third question. This [answer (and some comments there)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/2498729) talk about efficiency. Sets are an option too `x in {y, z}`.

Comment: I can't imagine that it would make any real difference. If it does, you should probably be using C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's test it out ourselves.

Here is a class that overloads the equality operator to let us see what Python is doing:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def __eq__(self, other):
    print self.name, "==", other.name, "?"
    return self.name == other.name
```

Let's test out short circuiting:

```
# x and a are passed the same string because we want x == a to be True
x = Foo("a")
a, b = Foo("a"), Foo("b")
if x in (a, b):
  print "Hello World!"
```

For me, this outputs:

```
a == a ?
Hello World!
```

`a == b ?` was not printed, so short-circuiting does work as desired. The block is also executed as desired.

Now for speed. If we modify the above `__eq__` method to **remove the print statement (to avoid I/O in our benchmark)** and use IPython's `%timeit` magic command, we can test it this way:

```
c = Foo("c") # for comparison when x is not equal to either case
%timeit x in (a, b) # equal to first case
%timeit (x == a or x == b)
%timeit x in (b, a) # equal to second case
%timeit (x == b or x == a)
%timeit x in (b, c) # not equal to either case
%timeit (x == b or x == c)
```

These are the average times per iteration (from 1 million iterations):

```
Code               Time (ns)
x in (a, b)        437
x == a or x == b   397
x in (b, a)        796
x == b or x == a   819
x in (b, c)        779
x == b or x == c   787
```

So, pretty comparable results. There is a slight difference, but it isn't big enough to worry about. Just use whichever is most readable in a case-by-case basis.

Comment: `x, y, z = X("x"),` **`X("x"),`** `X("z")` do you maybe mean to make the middle one `X("y")`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen no, because I wanted the equality operator to evaluate to `True` for that case. Maybe the class name and string value is a little confusing. For now I'll add a comment to explain it.

Comment: I'd just use `a` and `b` as the string if they do not directly represent the variable names, because yes it is really confusing.  Also tell me, did you remove the print statement in the `__eq__` before timing it?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I agree. I'll update the string values to those. Thanks. And yes, I removed the print statement (I mention it before the `%timeit` commands).

Comment: Thank you for your answer & the tests, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

For two choices, the first is more readable, for twenty, the second one. Performance is not a real issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it.

Comment: Dear pperry, as the previous answer from Alex Bowe shows, the second sentence is quite exact. Therefore the first sentence is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

When there are only two options this is really just opinion based, although I'd like to point out that if you need to check `x` against say 5 values there would be a more substantial difference:

```
if x == a or x == b or x == c or x == d or x == e:
```

vs:

```
if x in (a,b,c,d,e):
```

Especially if you need to later change it to `not in` vs all of the `==` to `!=` the second seems easier to expand upon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd plump for `if x == y or x == z`:

1. You can exploit the fact that `x == z` will *not* be evaluated if `x == y`.
2. Creating the anonymous temporary tuple is potentially an overhead.
3. `if x == y or x == z` is common in other languages too and so perhaps is more readable.

Perhaps though a good python interpreter can optimise out the anonymous temporary.

Comment: when checking `x in (y,z)` it will only check `x==z` if x was not equal to y so your first point isn't much of an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that python is a lazy langage, he won't check the second statement if he don't need to. But i don't know if your other method would be faster.

> Would Python not bother to check if x was equal to z if x was equal to y?

Yes, Python would not check it.

> Would Python still execute the code in the if statement if x was equal to y but not z

No, he won't.

Comment: Python itself is not a lazy language. `and` and `or` are defined as short-circuiting operators, evaluating the second argument only when necessary to define the entire expression.

Comment: yeah this  is what i meant to say

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it.